# How to save file without clicking the submit button ? Symfony 6.0.2

Tags: forms, symfony, error-handling, submit

**Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "password".**

I don't understand why I have this error when I submit my form. I wanted to be sure to not have problem any more by adding **'empty_data' => ''** to my password inputs, but it didn't solve the problem.

Note : I gave "d-none" class to password inputs and save button because thanks to onChange attribute, I wish to send directly the file when it's been uploaded.

edit.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form)  }}
    {{ form_widget(form.photo, {'attr' : {'onChange' : 'this.form.submit();'}} ) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.first, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.second, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'empty_data' => ''
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Les deux mots de passe doivent être identiques.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
                'empty_data' => ''
            ])
            ->add('photo', FileType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ]);
    }
}
```

SecurityController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\UserType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/login', name: 'login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
            
        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    #[Route('/profile', name: 'profile')]
    public function addPhoto(
        Request $request,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        SluggerInterface $sluggerInterface,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface
    ){
        $connected = $this->getUser();
        $useremail = $connected->getUserIdentifier();
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $useremail]);

        $userform = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $userform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userform->isSubmitted() && $userform->isValid()) {
            $imagefile = $userform->get('photo')->getData();

            if ($imagefile){
                $originalFileName = pathinfo($imagefile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $safeFileName = $sluggerInterface->slug($originalFileName);
                $newFileName = $safeFileName . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $imagefile->guessExtension();
    
                $imagefile->move(
                    $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
                    $newFileName
                );
    
                $user->setPhoto($newFileName);
            }

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($user);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }

        return $this->renderForm('security/login.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $userform,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

Comment: not enough information, totally unclear how your controller code looks like, if there's an error message and if so, what it says, and also maybe the code that handles any storage of a file that might have been uploaded ... ?

Comment: d-none is only for display... and in your form type, the password is required. set a default password or set `required` to `false`

Comment: [
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'empty_data' => '',
                ]

Comment: Hello. :) I wanted to set 'required' => false, but I want to have password required when I use the form in register.html.twig. Which is weird... because I don't need to fill password inputs when I edit my user informations in user_edit.html.twig.

Comment: EDIT : I just added the content of SecurityController.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "problem" is in `User::class` and not in SecurityController.php or somewhere else. To be more exact, in `setPassword()` method of your User-entity.

I assume your setter expecting **only** string

```php
/**
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword(string $password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}
```

Since you do not show password-field, and it stays empty it becomes NULL, but your `setPassword()` expects only string.

So you could change your setter to accept both types `string` **or** `null`

```php
/**
 * @param string|null $password
 */
public function setPassword(?string $password = null)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}
```

As an alternative, you can make your password-fields also disabled.
You'll need to use "setRendered()" on both fields to get rid of form-labels too.

```
{{ form_start(form)  }}
    {{ form_widget(form.photo, {'attr' : {'onChange' : 'this.form.submit();'}} ) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.first, {disabled: true, attr: { class: 'd-none' }} ) }}
    {% do form.password.first.setRendered %}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.second, {disabled: true, attr: { class: 'd-none' }} ) }}
    {% do form.password.second.setRendered %}
    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But it's not an ideal solution! I would reconsider `UserType::class` (maybe two different forms. One with password fields and another without.) Otherwise, you have to set your password-field as optional.

```php
//somewhere in your UserType::class

$builder->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [ 
 // your other options
 'required' => false,
]);
```